# Generating an audit report for WIX based installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Assume for a moment we have an installer based on [WIX (Windows Installer XML)](http://wixtoolset.org/) that doesn't use any custom actions other than that provided by WIX itself.  Now assume the installer (aka MSI) is being deployed into a highly regulated environment, so its important to audit exactly what is installed, modified and configured.

For example, the sort of thing Security Officers would like to know are

- Where are assemblies installed?
- What registry entries were modified?
- What windows services are installed?
- What firewall rules were modified?
- What IIS Websites are installed?

Does Windows Installer or WIX provide an existing mechanism to generate an audit report of what gets modified by an installer?

I found a [VBS at Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/msi-report-generator) that is a good starting point. Another alternative would be to using XSLT to transform the WIX XML into a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a tool that evaluates an MSI using the MSI APIs (the MSI file is a specialized database that can be queried) in ways similar to what the Windows Installer does and generate the report. That's essentially what the VBS you linked to does.

Totally possible but sounds tedious. Hope the Security Officers are paying well.

Comment: Seems simpler to analyse WIX xml instead.